# Is it possible for a Java Program to be an Email destination on Linux

Tags: java, linux, postfix-mta

Is it possible to have emails received by postfix delivered to a java program? I have a Linux system which uses Postfix to receive emails. I would like to use a Java program to process the raw email messages. In other words, I don't want to deal with protocols such as SMTP, IMAP, etc. I just want to the Postfix to pass the raw email message text to the Java program.

Comment: simillar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778562/postfix-message-received-hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [a command alias](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) in `/etc/aliases`, which has the form:

```
my-alias: "|/path/to/my/command param param"
```

Mail to `my-alias@example.com` will then be piped to `command`.